# How to conditionally decide type based on value of nested property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

The first example explains the behaviour I want:

```
type MyConditionType = {
  id: number;
} & (
  | {
      condition: 'BUY';
      key1: string;
    }
  | {
      condition: 'SELL';
      key2: string;
    }
);

const obj1: MyConditionType = { // This is a valid object
  id: 1,
  condition: 'BUY',
  key1: 'some value',
};

const obj1: MyConditionType = { // This is not a valid object
  id: 1,
  condition: 'SELL',
  key1: 'some value',
};
```

Just like the above example, I want the exact same behaviour but based on a nested condition object.

```
type MyConditionType2 = {
  id: number;
} & (
  | {
      condition: { name: 'BUY' };
      key1: string;
    }
  | {
      condition: { name: 'SELL' };
      key2: string;
    }
);

const obj2: MyConditionType2 = {
  id: 1,
  condition: { name: 'BUY' },
  key1: 'sda',
  key2: 'sde', // This should not be allowed here.
};
```

The `obj2.condition.name` should decide the presence of key1 or key2. The above code allows both `key1` and `key2` to be added to the object.

Comment: TS doesn't currently supported "nested discriminated unions"; see the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for commenting. I didn't know it's called "discriminated unions".

Comment: This worked for me:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758#issuecomment-1172487806